# I would like that a numeric list indicate movement when a value in the same row changes to another

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[An example of what im asking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlTYV.png)

Im asking if there's a way to "mark" in the B column when a value changes in position respect at the C column.

Like if new data came and the EXAMPLE1 changes to the C8 cell, that the number in the B8 column show that it has a lower position.

Sheet : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pLYqhkLuAS8ZgjPnsZTZyU5yuPXVgm0IRUPIF2FBKkM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Are the changes initiated by user edits or edits due to formulas or other scripts?

Comment: I pluck the data directly on a sheet [1], and a selective group of information goes to another sheet and from that to a dinamic table that organize the information. And this table picks the information from the dinamic table with =A2 [for example]

Comment: What does the term pluck mean? Is the process a user edit or a formula action?

Comment: I used a .csv and import the data on to one sheet an copy-paste that to the sheet [1]

Comment: Okay so it's not a user edit and therefore it will not generate a trigger to run a script.

Comment: A manual paste would generate an onedit trigger in the sheet that the paste occurs.

Comment: Im not following you. I have edited a link to the sheet

Comment: We seem to  have a failure to communicate here.  If the changes you wish to identify are caused by a user edit then a script solution is possible.  If they are not caused by a user edit then no trigger is available to run a script to generate any sort of visual modification to the spreadsheet.

Comment: I'm answering this question because you checked the google-apps-script tag.

Comment: Oh, okay, thanks for responding

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets are better formulated in numeric value. In view with your screenshot provided, I saw player, and I assumed your player comes with various other numerical value along such as scores, age, weight, etc.

With the aid of the numerical value, you can formulate a deductive relation by finding who is best ranked number 1.

Here's an example:

[image]

As you can see from the picture above, assumed the greater the age, the higher the rank, you may use `countif` to count the other bigger value, while you can combine use `count` for deduction, and that builds the sequence from getting number 1 the older, and last the younger

Hope you find it helpful